# Eclipse RCP: Using different JUnit version (4.3.1) than shipped with eclipse galileo (4.5.0)

Tags: junit, eclipse-rcp, classloader

Hallo,

I have the following situation:

We are developing an **Eclipse RCP Application** and want to switch from Eclipse 3.4 to **Eclipse 3.5**. Our JUnit-Tests are using JUnit 4.3.1 and we have a launch configuration to start our test suite. I think I don't need to go into more details here.

The problem is:

**Running the tests with Eclipse 3.5 does not work: JUnit cannot find any annotations in the test classes (neither (at)Test nor (at)RunWith).**

---

I patched the junit library with some logging output to check what is going on. I found out that this problem is a classloading issue:

**The test class passed to JUnit 'lies in' a ClassLoader which is different from the one JUnit uses to load the annotation classes like 'RunWith'. This is not the case in Eclipse 3.4**

```
in org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest:

public Runner getRunner() {   
    log("TestClass     ClassLoader: "+this.fTestClass.getClassLoader());
    log("RunWith.class ClassLoader: "+RunWith.class.getClassLoader());   
    ... // validating test class: searching for annotations and more

}
```

The first line prints another classloader than the second line. This is bad because JUnit **cannot match the annotations** in the test class with the Annotation-Class (here: RunWith.class): "RunWith" in CL1 is not equal to "RunWith" in CL2.

---

I have a solution which points to the core problem: **Replace JUnit 4.5 in Eclipse Galileo with JUnit 4.3.1** so that there is only one JUnit-Version: The Test-Run and the tests classes are both using JUnit 4.3.1 (*I had to patch "org.eclipse.jdt.junit4.runtime" to accept an ealier junit version*).

I think I can also replace JUnit 4.3.1 in my test class with Version 4.5, but that is not an option yet.

**Guess:** *The classloaders are different because the classes 'come from' different JUnit-Bundles: the testclass with its annotations from version 4.3.1 and the test runs in version 4.5*

**What I want to know:** Is there any other solution besides patching Eclipse (replace JUnit versions)? Any commandline argument or such? Any configuration to force Eclipse to Use JUnit 4.3.1?

*Any hints on the above described analysis are welcome!*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's what you're looking for but:

In the **Run Configuration** of your JUnit tests, you can choose the **Test Runner** you want to use (JUnit 4, JUnit 3...)